# "Milky" chocolate does not have milk as ingredient - implications?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, meat-and-milk

The hechsher on this chocolate says it is milky but it contains no milk.

How is that possible?

Would it be wrong for me to eat it after a meaty meal and if so why?
[image: back of chocolate pack]

Comment: Yes - I think it is a dup - and will delete it unless someone comments otherwise.

Comment: A lot of Swiss chocolate which is considered parve by the rabbanut in Switzerland gets a halavi status when imported in Israel. Same exact chocolate. But indeed different ways to consider the status of parve chocolate prepared on dairy equipment

Comment: Whaddayamean no dairy ingredients? It says חמאת קקאו (cocoa butter)! `:-)`

Comment: @msh210 ["Cocoa butter, also called theobroma oil, is a pale-yellow, edible vegetable fat extracted from the cocoa bean."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoa_butter)

Comment: Yes, it was a joke.

Comment: Mishenichnas Adar ...

Answer (score 8):

I had the same question concerning exactly this particular product. I called the chocolate company (Strauss - Illit) and was told that that chocolate is produced on the same machines as their milky chocolates without kashering the machines in between,thus rendering it milky although it contains no actual milk ingredient.

Nevertheless it would still be permitted to eat this chocolate after a meaty meal, since the waiting period after eating meat is required only for eating actual milky products but not parve products which became milky by absorbing milk- taste from a milky utensil.

Comment: This assuming that the parve chocolate is produced within 24 hours of the production of milky chocolate in the same machine. If more than 24 hours passes in between the milky production and the parve product then you could even eat the parve chocolate TOGETHER with meat.

Comment: in industrial settings the general rule of thumb is that machinery doesn't sit cold for 24 hours.

Comment: @shalom it can definitely sit without milk for 24 hours though. Plus the Rashba that cooking Pareve Kashers from Heter and plus the fact that Nat bar Nat is a Chumra that's Mutar Bedieved anyway and it's hard to see much reason to be strict here.

Comment: @DoubleAA - If the machines never sit cold for 24 hours then when the last run of milky chocolate ends, then the next run of Parve chocolate will begin within 24 hours of the milk use. Thus, the only way the chocolate could be from a machine that was without milk for 24 hours would be from the following run of parve chocolate, but the first parve run is always within 24 hours of the milky run.

Comment: An interesting point may be, that since we have no way of verifying if any particular chocolate bar came from the first  (ben-yomo) run of parve, or from a subsequent (aino ben yomo) run,  would we be able to rely on the rule that 'סתם כלים אינם בני יומן , (when in doubt we assume that a utensil was not used within 24 hours for meat/milk etc.), and thus assume any parve chocolate to be from the later [post 24 hr.] runs?